# WiFi repeatedly drops to 0% on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

Recently built a desktop and installed Linux Mint but having trouble with the WiFi. The main problem is that the WiFi connection keeps dropping. When connected, the strength is shown at ~70% and the WiFi is usable (I do encounter trouble with some streaming sites e.g. v.reddit.com and streamable.com, but others e.g. youtube.com are fine). However after some netowrk usage Linux Mint still reports it as connected but shows the network connection  at 0%, and it is not usable:

[image: WiFi connection at 0%]

When this happens, I've tried toggling WiFi off/on, and also `sudo service network-manager restart`. Both fix the problem temporarily but shortly after the problem occurs again (sometimes on the order of seconds-minutes). Same thing with restarting the whole machine.

The WiFi works great on every other device I own so its definitely a problem with this machine. I'm not dual booting.

The Wireless Adapter I'm using can be found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006WWMZSK).

Output of some commands, let me know if others would help too:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 16
       serial: e0:d5:5e:e1:2f:71
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a1204000-a1204fff memory:a1200000-a1203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 08:10:70:45:03:44
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ee driverversion=4.15.0-20-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.1.55 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a1103fff



$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"ALJOZIMA"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: F0:99:BF:07:F0:50 
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:6   Missed beacon:0

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.



$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=bb4cdd90-9cfc-488c-8bbc-387343b7b434 ro quiet splash pci=nomsi,noaer,nommconf vt.handoff=1



$ sudo lspci -vnn | grep Network
<...snipped...>
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:818b]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:818b]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at a1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ee
    Kernel modules: rtl8192ee


$ ifconfig
enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e0:d5:5e:e1:2f:71  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5837  bytes 468305 (468.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5837  bytes 468305 (468.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 08:10:70:45:03:44  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 167669  bytes 158516756 (158.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 136910  bytes 19684726 (19.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0



$ lsmod | grep wifi
iwlwifi               278528  0
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl8192ee,rtl_pci,btcoexist
mac80211              778240  3 rtl8192ee,rtl_pci,rtlwifi
cfg80211              622592  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,rtlwifi



$ dmesg | grep wifi
[ 2484.099772] Modules linked in: ccm nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic arc4 rtl8192ee btcoexist rtl_pci rtlwifi snd_hda_intel mac80211 snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi s
nd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_seq kvm joydev input_leds irqbypass snd_seq_device crct10dif_pclmul snd_timer crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cfg80211 wmi_bmof pcbc sn
d aesni_intel soundcore aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf mei_me mei shpchp intel_pch_thermal acpi_pad mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs xor zstd_compres
s raid6_pq dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_generic usbhid hid i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper
[ 2495.513098] rtlwifi: AP off, try to reconnect now
[ 2505.593086] rtlwifi: AP off, try to reconnect now
<...repeats many times...>



$ uname -r
4.15.0-20-generic



$ grep Network /sys/log/varlog
<...snipped...>
Jul  4 16:49:27 splash dbus-daemon[834]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.133' (uid=0 pid=9318 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jul  4 16:49:27 splash systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jul  4 16:49:27 splash systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul  4 16:49:39 splash dbus-daemon[834]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.133' (uid=0 pid=9318 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jul  4 16:49:39 splash systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jul  4 16:49:39 splash systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul  4 16:49:41 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284181.9757] sup-iface[0x560530fa9710,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul  4 16:49:41 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284181.9964] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:49:42 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284182.0810] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 16:49:49 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284189.8112] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 16:49:49 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284189.8784] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 16:49:49 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284189.8933] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul  4 16:49:49 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284189.9401] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul  4 16:50:13 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284213.1309] sup-iface[0x560530fa9710,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul  4 16:50:13 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284213.1512] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:50:13 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284213.2369] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 16:50:20 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284220.9472] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 16:50:20 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284220.9668] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 16:50:20 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284220.9808] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul  4 16:50:21 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284221.0284] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul  4 16:50:32 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284232.0878] sup-iface[0x560530fa9710,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul  4 16:50:32 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284232.1082] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:50:32 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284232.1930] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 16:50:39 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284239.9035] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 16:50:39 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284239.9527] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 16:50:39 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284239.9742] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul  4 16:50:40 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284240.0800] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul  4 16:51:21 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284281.4466] sup-iface[0x560530fa9710,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul  4 16:51:21 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284281.4671] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:51:21 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284281.5526] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 16:51:29 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284289.2512] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 16:51:29 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284289.2683] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 16:51:29 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284289.2944] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul  4 16:51:29 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284289.3012] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul  4 16:51:42 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284302.3835] sup-iface[0x560530fa9710,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul  4 16:51:42 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284302.4041] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:51:42 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284302.4888] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 16:51:50 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284310.1873] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 16:51:50 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284310.2067] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 16:51:50 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284310.2360] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul  4 16:51:50 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284310.2483] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul  4 16:52:09 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284329.3987] sup-iface[0x560530fa9710,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul  4 16:52:09 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284329.4192] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:52:09 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284329.5042] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 16:52:17 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284337.2230] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 16:52:17 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284337.2430] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 16:52:17 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284337.2643] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul  4 16:52:17 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284337.2901] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul  4 16:52:50 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284370.5106] sup-iface[0x560530fa9710,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul  4 16:52:50 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284370.5312] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:52:50 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284370.6165] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 16:52:58 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284378.3510] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 16:52:58 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284378.3939] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 16:52:58 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284378.4058] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jul  4 16:52:58 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284378.4116] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Jul  4 16:52:58 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284378.5033] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul  4 16:53:07 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284387.4234] sup-iface[0x560530fa9710,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul  4 16:53:07 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284387.4601] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:53:07 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284387.5287] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 16:53:15 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284395.2311] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 16:53:15 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284395.2530] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 16:53:15 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284395.2760] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul  4 16:53:15 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284395.3141] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul  4 16:53:48 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284428.5187] sup-iface[0x560530fa9710,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul  4 16:53:48 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284428.5392] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:53:48 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284428.6245] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 16:53:56 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284436.3351] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 16:53:56 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284436.3569] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 16:53:56 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284436.3768] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul  4 16:53:56 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284436.4176] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul  4 16:54:29 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284469.6347] sup-iface[0x560530fa9710,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul  4 16:54:29 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284469.6551] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:54:29 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284469.7407] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 16:54:37 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284477.4432] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 16:54:37 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284477.4805] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 16:54:37 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284477.4980] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul  4 16:54:37 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284477.5242] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul  4 16:54:56 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284496.6026] sup-iface[0x560530fa9710,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul  4 16:54:56 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284496.6231] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:54:56 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284496.7084] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 16:55:04 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284504.4190] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 16:55:04 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284504.4538] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 16:55:04 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284504.4676] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul  4 16:55:04 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284504.4827] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul  4 16:55:21 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284521.5706] sup-iface[0x560530fa9710,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul  4 16:55:21 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284521.5952] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:55:21 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284521.6766] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 16:55:29 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284529.3712] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 16:55:29 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284529.3990] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 16:55:29 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284529.4212] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul  4 16:55:29 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284529.4625] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul  4 16:55:44 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284544.5066] sup-iface[0x560530fa9710,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul  4 16:55:44 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284544.5312] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:55:44 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284544.6126] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 16:55:52 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284552.3151] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 16:55:52 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284552.3373] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 16:55:52 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284552.3575] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul  4 16:56:00 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284560.0051] device (wlp2s0): link timed out.
Jul  4 16:56:00 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284560.0053] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'supplicant-timeout', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 16:56:00 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284560.0056] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul  4 16:56:00 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284560.0061] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jul  4 16:56:00 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284560.0143] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Auto ALJOZIMA'
Jul  4 16:56:00 splash dbus-daemon[834]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.133' (uid=0 pid=9318 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jul  4 16:56:00 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284560.0172] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 16:56:00 splash systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jul  4 16:56:00 splash systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul  4 16:56:00 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284560.0831] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 13666
Jul  4 16:56:00 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284560.0832] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
Jul  4 16:56:00 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284560.1025] sup-iface[0x560530fa9710,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Jul  4 16:56:00 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284560.1025] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1522] policy: auto-activating connection 'Auto ALJOZIMA'
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1528] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'Auto ALJOZIMA' (c78541d0-1545-4a7a-85fc-6d75b2aea57b)
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1531] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1532] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1534] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1536] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Auto ALJOZIMA' has security, but secrets are required.
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1536] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1554] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1556] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1558] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Auto ALJOZIMA' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1558] Config: added 'ssid' value 'ALJOZIMA'
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1558] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1558] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1558] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1558] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.1802] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Jul  4 16:56:01 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284561.5326] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jul  4 16:56:02 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284562.0331] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 16:56:26 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284586.0029] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Jul  4 16:56:26 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284586.0030] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 16:56:26 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284586.0034] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jul  4 16:56:26 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <warn>  [1562284586.0047] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Auto ALJOZIMA'
Jul  4 16:56:26 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284586.0067] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 16:56:27 splash NetworkManager[9318]: <info>  [1562284587.1924] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
```

Comment: In had this problem with the Wi-Fi dropping out i solved it by using usb wireless off ebay £3 and have no problems since.

Answer (score 1):

disable power management for the wifi card: iwconfig wlp2s0 power off

push some more power: iwconfig wlp2s0 txpower 30mW

still got issues? i would try a different kernel (apt-cache search linux-image and apt-get install linux-image-VERSION)

later edit: it’s always worth a shot to try forced, slower but some say more stable, 802.11g or even 802.11b: iwconfig wlp2s0 modu 11b (not supported by all drivers) or iwconfig wlp2s0 rate 11M

Comment: I tried your first suggestion (haven't tried the second yet) but this hasn't fixed it - the WiFi seemed to be working fine for a while, but after leaving the computer idle for a while the issue reappeared.

Comment: @iobender most likely your 2.4 GHz is more crowded then hell itself. Try changing your routers channel (1, 6 or 11).

Comment: Also, to eliminate the OS/drivers as main suspects try a livecd of ubuntu, fedora or pcbsd to see if the problem persists. How far is your router from the computer? Also note that those changes to your wifi card are lost at reboot. Add as a parameter to modprobe.conf for persistency.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to also check even perhaps your routers own settings, some cards only support certain types.. is it a b/g/n what about the channels for your laptops card use 20hz 40hz 80hz... Maybe your wifi only uses 2.4 but your on a 5g... There are  wide variety of possible reasons ..

Also check and see if you've installed any and all DKMS which you might need.. Such as the Broadcom ndis wrapper . . .

Check out even compiling your own kernel from kernel.org. 
I also use mint, but I may make my move back over to Debian because I am mostly a fan of Cinnamon, however recently again..  the team of Mint ... Seems to be dropping the ball on delivery, or even availability of resources that work with thier so called kernel product ... As I've noticed, mind has a vast lack of firmware ... Period... If you download a Debian there is literally nothing left out.. even on kernel.org they have a huuuuuuuuuge array of firmware to load into your device and have your wanton funsies with... Presently my own Mint boxes are a Frankenstein of Kali/Parrot/Debian/Ubuntu/Gentoo/Centos/Slackware/Kali-ma!!!kali-maaa!!!Kali Maaaaa *plunging hand into an iOS and rips out Steve jobs' metaphorical iHeart*